# Length of BSTR (COM)

Tags: c#, c++, com

I have COM(c, c++) and application in C#.
I pass the variable `textbox.Text` in C# apllication to COM's function `Func(BSTR inData, BSTR outData)` like this: `Func(textbox.Text, outData)`.

And in C# application `textBox.Text.Length = 32` (for example), but in COM `SysStringLen(inData) = 40`. Why? And how can I fix it?

thank you in advance!

Best regards,

Mary

Comment: Extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence, I don't see any.  At the very minimum at least show us what the debugger told you about the actual string content both in the C# and the C++ code.

Answer (score 3):

From MSDN:

SysStringLen function

The returned value may be different from strlen(bstr) if the BSTR contains embedded Null characters.

Comment: when I write `strlen(inData)` I have error: type BSTR is incompatible with parameter of type "const char *".

Comment: Use wcslen, it is a widechar string.

Comment: I tried. wcslen returns 40 too. :(

Comment: Show the C# code of COM call.

Comment: And meanwhile compare 32 symbols of `textBox.Text` and `inData` manually.

Comment: Func(comboBox1.Text, flags, textBox7.Text, out outData);

Comment: inData contains 32 symbols of textBox.Text and 8 symbols `-85 '«' char`